# Is there a way to dynamically update a destination?

Tags: skmaps

I'm working on an app that has a leader pass their position to a client and I need to update the route destination dynamically. I am currently recreating the entire route but the recalculation causes the route to "blink" which I don't love. I'm open to any workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now this is not possible - you can dynamically change the via points on the route but not the route's destination (not without recreating the entire route).

We are exploring adding this possibility, by the end of this month we should have something in place (meaning that it should be ready for the 3.0.2 update).